# wildfly not loading class from web.xml

Tags: xml, exception, web.xml, wildfly, wildfly-8

Am unable to run the war, as i configured all the modules in wildfly,
and this war is running good in jboss 6 with same web.xml config, and when i deploy in wildfly after all setup for migration then am getting classNotFound Exception as i have few servlet mapping in web.xml

for more info please find below

in Wildfly am getting below Exception :

Here is web.xml

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        version="2.5">

```
  <display-name>Test </display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>messages</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>exportFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>messageFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.Test.us.web.MessageFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter>
</web-app>
```

Here is My Log :

```
17:16:04,774 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC0000
01: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-hos
t./.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in servi
ce jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./.UndertowDeploymentInf
oService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.Test.us.web.MessageFilter fr
om [Module "deployment.TestRWD_JB60_Testing.war:main" from Service Module Lo
ader]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoServi
ce.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:933)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoServi
ce.start(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:256)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(Se
rviceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceCont
rollerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.Test.us.web.MessageFilter f
rom [Module "deployment.TestRWD_JB60_Testing.war:main" from Service Module L
oader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:
213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(Con
currentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(Concu
rrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentCl
assLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoad
er.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoServi
ce.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:724)
        ... 6 more


17:16:04,861 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentSca
nner-threads - 2) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deploym
ent" => "TestRWD_JB60_Testing.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: F
ailed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./.Und
ertowDeploymentInfoService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./.UndertowDeploymentInfoSe
rvice: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.Test.us.web.MessageFilter from
[Module \"deployment.TestRWD_JB60_Testing.war:main\" from Service Module Loa
der]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.Test.us.web.MessageFilt
er from [Module \"deployment.TestRWD_JB60_Testing.war:main\" from Service Mo
dule Loader]"}}
17:16:05,048 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018
559: Deployed "TestRWD_JB60_Testing.war" (runtime-name : "TestRWD_JB60_T
esting.war")
17:16:05,052 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBA
S014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deploy
ment.default-server.default-host./.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.
service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.defau
lt-host./.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.Test.us.web.MessageFilter from [Module "deployment.TestRWD_JB60_Testing.w
ar:main" from Service Module Loader]
- See more at: https://developer.jboss.org/message/929842#929842
```

Comment: Did you set them up as modules or put them in your WAR/lib directory?

Comment: i set com.Test.us.web.MessageFilter in war WEB-INF/classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your class `com.Test.us.web.MessageFilter` is not visible for the classloader. There are 2 options where you can put the class:

1. directly in the WAR **deployment**

   - either in the `WEB-INF/lib/some.jar`
   - or expanded into the `WEB-INF/classes`
2. in a custom WildFly **module**. In this case you've to add the module dependency into the deployment. The module dependencies can be defined in following files:

   - either `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`
   - or in `META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml`

Sample content of the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file is:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="your.custom.module"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Thanks the issue is fixed by adding jar in lib folder, Thanks for the help.

Comment: For me even after mapping libs and classes to WildFly deployment folder, I was facing the issue.

Comment: what does it mean "mapping libs and classes to WildFly deployment folder", @SatyaMahesh?

Comment: In eclipse deployment assembly structure I mapped /classes to WildFly WEB-INF/classes
and /lib to WildFly WEB-INF/lib like mentioned above.

Comment: I tried both options but still i am facing the issue.